# MySQL COUNT distinct total where ALL/EVERY joined = a given value

Tags: mysql, database, join, count, having-clause

I've tried to simplify this as much as possible with simple sample data. I have a table called Assignments and a table called Tasks:

**Assignments**

```
+---------------+------------------+
| ASSIGNMENT_ID |  ASSIGNMENT_NAME |
+---------------+------------------+
|               |                  |
| 1             |  Morning Tasks   |
|               |                  |
| 2             |  Afternoon Tasks |
|               |                  |
| 3             |  Evening Tasks   |
+---------------+------------------+
```

**Tasks**

```
+---------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| TASK_ID |  ASSIGNMENT_ID |    TASK_NAME   |  TASK_STATUS |
+---------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
|         |                |                |              |
| 1       |  1             |  Make Bed      |  2           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 2       |  1             |  Brush Teeth   |  2           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 3       |  1             |  Eat Breakfast |  2           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 4       |  1             |  Commute       |  2           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 5       |  2             |  Eat Lunch     |  2           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 5       |  2             |  Wash Dishes   |  1           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 6       |  2             |  Wash Table    |  1           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 7       |  3             |  Make Supper   |  1           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 8       |  3             |  Eat Supper    |  1           |
|         |                |                |              |
| 9       |  3             |  Wash Dishes   |  1           |
+---------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

In the task status, 1 means not complete, and 2 means complete.

For each assignment, there are related tasks. I want to get a count of all the assignments where ALL of the associated tasks are complete (TASK_STATUS = 2) (In my actual use case, meeting a bunch of other criteria as well, but that's outside of this sample.)

So in this example, the answer should be **"1"**. ***Not a list of results, just the number of them.*** (Just the morning tasks are complete, the afternoon tasks have been started, but not all of them are complete.)

I don't want to know how many tasks are complete, or how many assignments have been started, just how many assignments are 100% complete.

I've tried several ways but am hitting a mental block...

*This will give me all the assignments where there is a completed task*

```
SELECT COUNT(a.assignment_id) AS completed_assignments
FROM assignments AS a
JOIN tasks AS t ON a.assignment_id = t.assignment_id 
WHERE t.task_status = 2
LIMIT 1;
```

*This will also give me all the assignments where there is a completed task*

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN t.task_status = 2 THEN t.assignment_id ELSE NULL END)) AS completed_assignments
FROM assignments AS a
JOIN tasks AS t ON a.assignment_id = t.assignment_id 
WHERE t.task_status = 2
LIMIT 1;
```

But I want where **ALL** tasks are complete. **(Just a count of how many are completed, not a listing of all the results.)**

*This will give the number of results (in resulting rows, which I could count), but I need the value within the query (to perform other calculations with)*

```
SELECT a.assignment_id,
(COUNT(CASE WHEN t.task_status = 2 THEN t.task_id ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(t.task_id)*100) AS percent_complete
FROM assignments AS a
JOIN tasks AS t ON a.assignment_id = t.assignment_id 
GROUP BY a.assignment_id 
HAVING percent_complete = 100;
```

*Number of results equals the total*

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not `NULL`s in `TASK_STATUS` of `Tasks` then join and `group by assignment_id` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select a.assignment_id, a.assignment_name 
from assignments a inner join tasks t
on t.assignment_id = a.assignment_id
group by a.assignment_id, a.assignment_name
having sum(t.task_status = 1) = 0
```

If you only need the assignment's id then you don't need the table `Assignments`:

```
select assignment_id
from tasks
group by assignment_id
having sum(task_status = 1) = 0
```

If you want the count of these assignments:

```
select count(*) from (
  select assignment_id
  from tasks
  group by assignment_id
  having sum(task_status = 1) = 0
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xz1Wfx8EtBMCKBTUDH9yCa/1).

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but I'm looking for a count of completed, not a listing...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `all count = count case when status = 2` to do it.

```sql
select * 
from Assignments
where ASSIGNMENT_ID  in (
    select 
        ASSIGNMENT_ID 
    from Tasks
    group by ASSIGNMENT_ID
    having count(1) = count(case when TASK_STATUS = '2' then 1 end)
)
```

---

#### Update :

> Appreciate the effort, but I'm looking for a count of completed, not a listing

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Tasks
>   (`TASK_ID` int, `ASSIGNMENT_ID` int, `TASK_NAME` varchar(13), `TASK_STATUS` int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Tasks
>   (`TASK_ID`, `ASSIGNMENT_ID`, `TASK_NAME`, `TASK_STATUS`)
> VALUES
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (1, 1, 'Make Bed', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (2, 1, 'Brush Teeth', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (3, 1, 'Eat Breakfast', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (4, 1, 'Commute', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (5, 2, 'Eat Lunch', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (5, 2, 'Wash Dishes', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (6, 2, 'Wash Table', 2),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (7, 3, 'Make Supper', 1),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (8, 3, 'Eat Supper', 1),
>   (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   (9, 3, 'Wash Dishes', 1)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Assignments
>   (`ASSIGNMENT_ID` int, `ASSIGNMENT_NAME` varchar(15))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Assignments
>   (`ASSIGNMENT_ID`, `ASSIGNMENT_NAME`)
> VALUES
>   (NULL, NULL),
>   (1, 'Morning Tasks'),
>   (NULL, NULL),
>   (2, 'Afternoon Tasks'),
>   (NULL, NULL),
>   (3, 'Evening Tasks')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select count(1) completedCount
> from (
>     select 
>         ASSIGNMENT_ID 
>     from Tasks
>     group by ASSIGNMENT_ID
>     having count(1) = count(case when TASK_STATUS = '2' then 1 end)
> ) T
> ```
>
> ```
> | completedCount |
> | -------------: |
> |              2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7283acc055e49140d3e30d0c74702de)*

Comment: demo link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7651a017b0dce89535ddc148e285a52

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but I'm looking for a count of completed, not a listing...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of joining and aggregating, you can filter with a `not exists` condition and a correlated subquery that ensures that there is no record in the `task` table with a status other than `2`:

```
select count(*)
from assignments a
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tasks t
    where 
        t.assignment_id = a.assignment_id
        and t.task_status != 2
)
```

With an index on `task(assignment_id, task_status)`, this should be an efficient option.

If you want the assignment list, you can replace `count(*)` with `*`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b82f89fa3d654fded140a716c199c98)**:

Count:

```
| count(*) |
| -------: |
|        1 |
```

Details:

```
ASSIGNMENT_ID | ASSIGNMENT_NAME
------------: | :--------------
            1 | Morning Tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Received some good answers (and accepted one), but couldn't get any of their methods to result in the correct answer with the rest of my query. For future reference, here's what I ended up with:

```
SELECT COUNT(ptc) AS completed_assignments
FROM (SELECT
(COUNT(CASE WHEN task_status = 2 THEN t.task_status ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(t.task_status)) AS ptc
FROM assignments AS a
JOIN tasks AS t ON a.assignment_id = t.assignment_id
WHERE [Other Conditions]
GROUP BY a.assignment_id
HAVING ptc = 1) T
```

This might not be the most efficient, but I'm able to get the right answer with it in my situation...